# Compute distance between skeletal keypoints in pose detection mlkits then store in Firebase datase

Tags: android, android-studio, google-mlkit, pose-detection

i'm using the google provide sample for pose detection in an android app.
I would get automatically distances beetween Keypoints placed by Pose (rightKnee to rightAnkle by example). I willing to store the data in Firebase datase

I think the here is the java class i shoulld modifie

Hope someone could help with a tip

````
public class PoseGraphic extends Graphic {

  private static final float DOT_RADIUS = 10.0f;
  private static final float IN_FRAME_LIKELIHOOD_TEXT_SIZE = 30.0f;
  private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 8.0f;

  private final Pose pose;
  private final boolean showInFrameLikelihood;
  private final boolean visualizeZ;
  private final boolean rescaleZForVisualization;
  private float zMin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
  private float zMax = Float.MIN_VALUE;

  private final Paint leftPaint;
  private final Paint rightPaint;
  private final Paint whitePaint;
  PoseGraphic(
      GraphicOverlay overlay,
      Pose pose,
      boolean showInFrameLikelihood,
      boolean visualizeZ,
      boolean rescaleZForVisualization) {
    super(overlay);
    this.pose = pose;
    this.showInFrameLikelihood = showInFrameLikelihood;
    this.visualizeZ = visualizeZ;
    this.rescaleZForVisualization = rescaleZForVisualization;

    whitePaint = new Paint();
    whitePaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    whitePaint.setTextSize(IN_FRAME_LIKELIHOOD_TEXT_SIZE);
    whitePaint.setDither(true);
    whitePaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    whitePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    whitePaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10, 40,}, 0));



    leftPaint = new Paint();
    leftPaint.setDither(true);
    leftPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    leftPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    leftPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10, 40,}, 0));
    leftPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    leftPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);


    rightPaint = new Paint();
    rightPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    rightPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    rightPaint.setDither(true);
    rightPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    rightPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    rightPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10, 40,}, 0));
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    List<PoseLandmark> landmarks = pose.getAllPoseLandmarks();
    if (landmarks.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }

    // Draw all the points
    for (PoseLandmark landmark : landmarks) {
      drawPoint(canvas, landmark, whitePaint);
      if (visualizeZ && rescaleZForVisualization) {
        zMin = min(zMin, landmark.getPosition3D().getZ());
        zMax = max(zMax, landmark.getPosition3D().getZ());
      }
    }

    PoseLandmark leftShoulder = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER);
    PoseLandmark rightShoulder = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER);
    PoseLandmark leftElbow = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW);
    PoseLandmark rightElbow = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW);
    PoseLandmark leftWrist = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST);
    PoseLandmark rightWrist = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST);
    PoseLandmark leftHip = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP);
    PoseLandmark rightHip = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP);
    PoseLandmark leftKnee = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_KNEE);
    PoseLandmark rightKnee = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_KNEE);
    PoseLandmark leftAnkle = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_ANKLE);
    PoseLandmark rightAnkle = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ANKLE);

    PoseLandmark leftPinky = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_PINKY);
    PoseLandmark rightPinky = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_PINKY);
    PoseLandmark leftIndex = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_INDEX);
    PoseLandmark rightIndex = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_INDEX);
    PoseLandmark leftThumb = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_THUMB);
    PoseLandmark rightThumb = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_THUMB);
    PoseLandmark leftHeel = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_HEEL);
    PoseLandmark rightHeel = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HEEL);
    PoseLandmark leftFootIndex = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_FOOT_INDEX);
    PoseLandmark rightFootIndex = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX);

    drawLine(canvas, leftShoulder, rightShoulder, whitePaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftHip, rightHip, whitePaint);

    // Left body
    drawLine(canvas, leftShoulder, leftElbow, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftElbow, leftWrist, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftShoulder, leftHip, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftHip, leftKnee, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftKnee, leftAnkle, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftWrist, leftThumb, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftWrist, leftPinky, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftWrist, leftIndex, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftIndex, leftPinky, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftAnkle, leftHeel, leftPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, leftHeel, leftFootIndex, leftPaint);

    // Right body
    drawLine(canvas, rightShoulder, rightElbow, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightElbow, rightWrist, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightShoulder, rightHip, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightHip, rightKnee, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightKnee, rightAnkle, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightWrist, rightThumb, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightWrist, rightPinky, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightWrist, rightIndex, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightIndex, rightPinky, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightAnkle, rightHeel, rightPaint);
    drawLine(canvas, rightHeel, rightFootIndex, rightPaint);

    // Draw inFrameLikelihood for all points
    if (showInFrameLikelihood) {
      for (PoseLandmark landmark : landmarks) {
        canvas.drawText(
            String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", landmark.getInFrameLikelihood()),
            translateX(landmark.getPosition().x),
            translateY(landmark.getPosition().y),
            whitePaint);
      }
    }
  }

  void drawPoint(Canvas canvas, PoseLandmark landmark, Paint paint) {
    PointF point = landmark.getPosition();
    canvas.drawCircle(translateX(point.x), translateY(point.y), DOT_RADIUS, paint);
  }

  void drawLine(Canvas canvas, PoseLandmark startLandmark, PoseLandmark endLandmark, Paint paint) {
    // When visualizeZ is true, sets up the paint to draw body line in different colors based on
    // their z values.
    if (visualizeZ) {
      PointF3D start = startLandmark.getPosition3D();
      PointF3D end = endLandmark.getPosition3D();

      // Gets the range of z value.
      float zLowerBoundInScreenPixel;
      float zUpperBoundInScreenPixel;

      if (rescaleZForVisualization) {
        zLowerBoundInScreenPixel = min(-0.001f, scale(zMin));
        zUpperBoundInScreenPixel = max(0.001f, scale(zMax));
      } else {
        // By default, assume the range of z value in screen pixel is [-canvasWidth, canvasWidth].
        float defaultRangeFactor = 1f;
        zLowerBoundInScreenPixel = -defaultRangeFactor * canvas.getWidth();
        zUpperBoundInScreenPixel = defaultRangeFactor * canvas.getWidth();
      }

      // Gets average z for the current body line
      float avgZInImagePixel = (start.getZ() + end.getZ()) / 2;
      float zInScreenPixel = scale(avgZInImagePixel);

      if (zInScreenPixel < 0) {
        // Sets up the paint to draw the body line in red if it is in front of the z origin.
        // Maps values within [zLowerBoundInScreenPixel, 0) to [255, 0) and use it to control the
        // color. The larger the value is, the more red it will be.
        int v = (int) (zInScreenPixel / zLowerBoundInScreenPixel * 255);
        v = Ints.constrainToRange(v, 0, 255);
        paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255 - v, 255 - v);
      } else {
        // Sets up the paint to draw the body line in blue if it is behind the z origin.
        // Maps values within [0, zUpperBoundInScreenPixel] to [0, 255] and use it to control the
        // color. The larger the value is, the more blue it will be.
        int v = (int) (zInScreenPixel / zUpperBoundInScreenPixel * 255);
        v = Ints.constrainToRange(v, 0, 255);
        paint.setARGB(255, 255 - v, 255 - v, 255);
      }

      canvas.drawLine(
          translateX(start.getX()),
          translateY(start.getY()),
          translateX(end.getX()),
          translateY(end.getY()),
          paint);

    } else {
      PointF start = startLandmark.getPosition();
      PointF end = endLandmark.getPosition();
      canvas.drawLine(
          translateX(start.x), translateY(start.y), translateX(end.x), translateY(end.y), paint);
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is. You are getting the keypoints right now and are trying to understand how to use Firebase Real-time Datastore or Cloud Firestore? Please clarify the question, thanks!

Comment: Yes, i'm getting the Keypoints.... But what i'm willing to do is calculate distance between two keypoints and store this distance in Firebase Realtime Database.... Then i could have  "Arm length" and so on, stored in my database

Comment: Ok, in that case, what is your specific question? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start should give good step by step instructions on how to use Firebase Realtime Database on Android.

Comment: I can post and retrieve data in Firebase, don't bother about that.... What i'm looking for is to know what class of Google ML kits pose detection sample to consider and what line, if i want calculate distance of the  body shape

Comment: The API provides the X and Y coordinates for each key-point which you should be able to use to calculate the distance between two points pretty easily. We don't have specific sample code for that, sorry.

Comment: Hi, i have foud this tips https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/classifying-poses ....Hope it could help other people